# Trying to change cell content doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to change the background color of a cell after the user enters something in a textfield. I've tried the following code but nothing happens.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Is there anything I don't see?

Comment: What do you see when you log `cell`?

Comment: try to [tableView reloadData]; after the cell is being updated

Comment: `UITableViewCell` behaves in a weird way (smells like a design error on part of Apple). You can't change most of its UI-related properties at an arbitrary time because setting them will not take effect. You have to subclass `UITableViewCell` and perform customization in its `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: @Bejibun shan't affect that. `backgroundColor` is a property on `UIView`. How *possibly* could it be updated on a generic view (i. e. one that is not a table view cell) if it took affect only a `reloadData`?

Comment: @rebello95 <UITableViewCell: 0x144d22210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x17803e200>>

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant do you have any link explaining how to do that?

Comment: @user3347446 http://google.com/search?q=ios+create+custom+uitableviewcell+subclass

Comment: @user3347446 well one problem is that the `frame` is `CGRectZero`

Comment: you could also try `[[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];`

Comment: @rebello95 as I explained above (`^^`), table view cells behave quite differently. They are not even laid out until the table view needs them. (Don't know about iOS 7+, but up until iOS 6, this was always the case, resulting in a bunch of counter-intuitive properties and behaviors, for which table cells were/are a pain in the neck to work with.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes, I suppose that's true. If the cell exists (and is currently showing, which it doesn't look like it is), he should be able to set the color without subclassing it, right? I know I've done it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you have your section/row number wrong, i.e.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2];
```

I have two sections in my tableView and it works as long as refer to section 2 as section 1, as section and row numbers start at 0. Apologies in advance if this sounds too obvious, but I do it all the time... :-)